# Creating a table using google app script from a query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-query-language

I have successfully been able to create a google chart by querying a google sheet that I have. I'm trying to create a table by querying the same google sheet, but I'm not getting any results. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is :/ Here's the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
function drawTable() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1ZxBkX5lTidV2LJvSJYjBQfILF3PlIYjeNgDqsHZoMqo&tq=select%20D%2C%20S%2C%20T%2C%20U%20where%20D%3C%3E%22Avatar%22');

  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

var options = {'title':'Bass Naming',
                 'width':'927',
                 'height':'510'};

table.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

<title>Data from a Spreadsheet</title>
</head>

<body>
<span id='columnchart'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var table = new
>   google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

You do not have any element with `id="table_div"` in your html code, so you won't see you data table displayed in your page.

Check your browser's javascript console for any other errors you may have in your page.

Also, is this code from a general basic html application, or from an HTML file in Google Apps Script project, server by HTMLService? Just asking because GAS HTML Service does not always play well with Google Visualization API due to sandbox restrictions and Caja sanitization.

Comment: Okay. Any idea how to fix it? I'm not really a web developer, I just kind of hack things together until it works the way I want it to.

I'm using a Wix page, so it's some sort of HTML widget that can placed on the page. My other charts work just fine, but I'm trying to convert my chart code so that it displays a table instead.

Comment: For starters, change your `<span id="columnchart"></span>` to `<div id="table_div"></div>`. See if that makes your table chart appear. If not, we'll need to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks...that fixed it :) I appreciate the help, truly (and so do my students).