# Querying data in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-query-language

I don't see this explicitly mentioned anywhere, but is it possible to do some sort of data query like it's mentioned in the google charts reference?https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries

I'm looking to start a project and this will have a big impact on whether or not I'll use Google Charts or Google Scripts.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible.

## Explanation

### Exhibit 1:

See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets

## Exhibit 2:

At this time there are 6 questions returned by searching [[google-apps-script][google-query-language]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+google-query-language). I picked one that could serve you as a place where is explicitly mentioned:

- [Creating a table using google app script from a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446815/creating-a-table-using-google-app-script-from-a-query)

## Exhibit 3:

At this time there are 137 questions returned by [[google-apps-script][google-visualization]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+google-visualization). I picked one that could serve you as place where is explicitly mentioned:

- [Google Visualization Column Chart set a data column from query as role: "Style"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705324/google-visualization-column-chart-set-a-data-column-from-query-as-role-style)